# Getting error on Kafka as and consumer is not able to read from topics -- Failed authentication with /10.2.***.* (SSL handshake failed)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am using apachekafka latest version 2.3.0, I am deploying kafka as a multi node cluster and using SSL for interbroker communication.
The set up is deployed onto kubernetes

---

### server.properties

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOU

T WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
# broker.id=0

# Switch to enable topic deletion or not, default value is false
#delete.topic.enable=true

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = security_protocol://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=SSL://0.0.0.0:9093,PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set,
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka.hfdevlabs.com:9092

# The number of threads handling network requests
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads doing disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
#log.dirs=/data

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to exceessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
#zookeeper.connect=zookeeper.hfdevlabs.com:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

api.version.request=true

#############################   ###################
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.secure.random.implementation=SHA1PRNG
########################## Properties #######################
advertised.listeners=SSL://kafka-1.qa.*******.com:9093,PLAINTEXT://kafka-1.qa.******.com:9092
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-0.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:2181,zookeeper-1.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:2181,zookeeper-2.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:2181
broker.id=1
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/config/tls/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=******
ssl.key.password=*****
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/kafka/config/tls/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=*****
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
log.dirs=/data/kafka-logs
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
default.replication.factor=3
offsets.retention.minutes=10080
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=60000
```

---

The command to generate the producer logs works fine for me

```
echo "test" | sh kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list  kafka-1.qa.******.com:9092 --topic test
```

However I am not able to consume the logs:

./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-1.qa.*****.com:9092 --topic test --from-beginning

---

The server logs shows the error as:

```
[2019-10-25 10:07:55,589] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Failed authentication with /10.2.***.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-10-25 10:07:56,028] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Failed authentication with /10.2.***.0 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your producer is working since you did not provide producer.config containing information for connecting to secured kafka cluster.

So the CLI producer command should be like

```
kafka-console-producer –broker-list kafka.example.com:9093 –topic securing-kafka –producer.config /etc/kafka/producer_ssl.properties message1
```

and the sample producer_ssl.properties like

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka.example.com:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/security/tls/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/security/tls/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
```

Same for CLI kafka consumer

```
kafka-console-consumer –bootstrap-server kafka.example.com:9093 –topic securing-kafka –new-consumer –from-beginning –consumer.config /etc/kafka/consumer_ssl.properties
```

https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/

Comment: yes producer is working not getting any error when I use this command "echo "test" | sh kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list  kafka-1.qa.******.com:9092 --topic test
" I am testing this on one of the multibroker pod only.